# Android- noHistory = true not working when come back from recents

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm following the next flow, Start activity A (loading resources), then go to Activity B (login). I marked Activity A as noHistory = "true" and just after I start the activity B I call finish() on activity A.

The app works as expected and when I pressed the back button from the Activity B the app closes, when I pressed the recents button and select my app, it restarts from activity A, I want it to starts from activity B.

thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your activity declaration in the `AndroidManifest`:

```
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

And it will be excluded from the "recent apps" list

Comment: its not working if recent button is clicked , else if we click home botton then its showing in recent list

Comment: @AmitVerma can you reproduce this issue in an emulator?

Comment: This is working fine with my case, I can know let user open the app once again and sees no glitch when pressed home button to reactivate Google TTS while pressing a button to trigger. Good code, but not perfect because user may figure this and founds irritated. I'm not sure because some maybe enjoy this feature because we everytime forgot recently opened application for some reason.

Comment: @Bay don't worry - it excludes only the activity you want to exclude. Don't add this to the main activity.

Answer (score 1):

that is expected behaviour . Since you have pressed the back button the app is closed , if you launch from recent after that its like clicking on app icon to launch the app . You can use shared preferences to save if the first activity is already launched you can directly launch second activity

Comment: Can I remove the app from recents when I push the back button?